# How to trigger css animation on page scroll with flexible height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

my design is using a height: 100%; for the top image - so is there any way to trigger a css3 animation like the one on the top image when the user scrolls down to another section of the page and not just on the page load?

My design;
if you scroll to the bottom (quality networks) and refresh the page you can see what i want, but I only want it to trigger when the user has scrolled down to that section

http://www.webxury.net/datacenter/

I want to make the content below like this site when the user scrolls down the text/images fades in from the sides

http://cloudfire.uk/

HTML

```
<div id="animated-example" class="animated fadeInDown"></div>
```

CSS

```
.animated { 
-webkit-animation-duration: 1s; 
animation-duration: 1s; 
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: both; 
animation-fill-mode: both; 
} 

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInDown { 
0% { 
    opacity: 0; 
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px); 
} 
100% { 
    opacity: 1; 
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0); 
} 
} 

@keyframes fadeInDown { 
0% { 
    opacity: 0; 
    transform: translateY(-20px); 
} 
100% { 
    opacity: 1; 
    transform: translateY(0); 
} 
} 

.fadeInDown { 
-webkit-animation-name: fadeInDown; 
animation-name: fadeInDown; 
}
```

Comment: If you inspect the page, you'll see that they are using [wow.js](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/index.html).

Comment: any solution you found? I have the same problem!